How can I get my threads to successfully go by a simulated clock?
I have a simulation project I am performing in python, in which many worker threads attempt to complete tasks and keep track of how long it takes them. These tasks come in at various times and lock down different resources.
To do this, I have 1 thread for each of the workers, and one thread who's whole purpose in life is to just keep track of the clock. However, despite that, it seems the worker threads miss some of the "seconds" tracked by the clock thread.
Is there a better way to do this where it doesn't miss the time?
Here's the output that shows the variable "all_time" (my clock in this case) and that it skips over some values.
I've tried with multiple worker threads, and I've tried with just one.
I'm not even sure how best to word the question, so if you've got a better way of phrasing the question I'd love to hear it.
current output:
                 WHO WHEN
0   WORKER0(0-14400)    0
1   WORKER0(0-14400)    1
2   WORKER0(0-14400)    2
3   WORKER0(0-14400)    3
4   WORKER0(0-14400)    6
5   WORKER0(0-14400)   11
6   WORKER0(0-14400)   12
7   WORKER0(0-14400)   15
8   WORKER0(0-14400)   17
9   WORKER0(0-14400)   18
10  WORKER0(0-14400)   21
11  WORKER0(0-14400)   24
12  WORKER0(0-14400)   26
13  WORKER0(0-14400)   27
14  WORKER0(0-14400)   29
15  WORKER0(0-14400)   30
16  WORKER0(0-14400)   31
17  WORKER0(0-14400)   32
18  WORKER0(0-14400)   33
19  WORKER0(0-14400)   35

expected output:
                 WHO WHEN
0   WORKER0(0-14400)    0
1   WORKER0(0-14400)    1
2   WORKER0(0-14400)    2
3   WORKER0(0-14400)    3
4   WORKER0(0-14400)    4
5   WORKER0(0-14400)    5
6   WORKER0(0-14400)    6
7   WORKER0(0-14400)    7
8   WORKER0(0-14400)    8
9   WORKER0(0-14400)    9
10  WORKER0(0-14400)   10
11  WORKER0(0-14400)   11
12  WORKER0(0-14400)   12
13  WORKER0(0-14400)   13
14  WORKER0(0-14400)   14
15  WORKER0(0-14400)   15
16  WORKER0(0-14400)   16
17  WORKER0(0-14400)   17
18  WORKER0(0-14400)   18
19  WORKER0(0-14400)   19

Code:
import random
import threading
import time
import pandas as pd

stop_event = threading.Event()
clock_lock = threading.Condition()
clock_time = 0
all_time = 0
days_running = 1

issue_lock = threading.Condition()
issue_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["WHO","WHEN"])
##bus.emit("ISSUE", [who, what, where, when, why])

def clean_issue_list():
    global issue_df
    issue_df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True,ignore_index=True)
    issue_df.sort_values(by = ["WHEN"], inplace = True,ignore_index=True)

from event_bus import EventBus

bus = EventBus()

@bus.on('ISSUE')
def issuehandler(msg):
    global issue_list
    global issue_df
    issue_lock.acquire()
    issue_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([msg[:]], columns=issue_df.columns), issue_df], ignore_index=True)
    issue_lock.release()

def worker(starttime,endtime,max_stack_height,efficiancy, startzone, allowed_zones = []): #thread? maybe? 
    global clock_time
    global all_time
    global taskqueue
    global zonelist
    who = threading.current_thread().name
    current_task = None
    current_zone = startzone
    allowedtime = starttime #allowed time is the time its allowed to start working
        #reset it to be the end time of its current task after every action
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        clock_lock.acquire()
        now = all_time
        clock_lock.release()
        if now >= allowedtime and now < endtime:            #get a task
            clock_lock.acquire()
            bus.emit("ISSUE", [who, all_time])
            clock_lock.release()



def work_clock(): #make this a thread, have it just constantly update a clock over and over again
    global clock_time
    global all_time
    global days_running
    maxtime = 60*60*24
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        clock_lock.acquire()
        clock_time+=1
        all_time+=1
        if clock_time >= maxtime:
            clock_time = 0
            days_running -= 1
            if days_running <= 0:
                stop_event.set()
        clock_lock.release()
        

def main_work():
    global standard_move
    global standard_restack
    global issue_df
    all_threads = []
    
    #workers
    workcount = 1
    workdaystart = 0
    workdayend = 60*60*4
    workmaxstack = 1
    workefficiancy=.95
    workstartzone = "Receiving"
    workzones = ["Charge","Receiving"]

    
    while workdayend < 60*60*24:
        count = 0
        for _ in range(workcount):
           all_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=worker,
                              args=[workdaystart,workdayend,workmaxstack,
                                    workefficiancy,workstartzone,workzones]))
           all_threads[-1].name = "WORKER"+str(count)+"("+str(workdaystart)+"-"+str(workdayend)+")"
           count+=1
        workdaystart = workdayend + 30*60
        workdayend = workdaystart + 60*60*4

        

    all_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=work_clock))

    print("Start!")
    timea = time.time()


    for t in all_threads:
        t.start()

    for t in all_threads:
        t.join()

    timeb = time.time()

    print(timeb-timea)


    

def main_issues():
    global issue_df
    clean_issue_list()
    print(issue_df.head(20))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main_work()
    main_issues()




I also have a "monitor thread"; a few actually; that run at different resolutions. A "counting" thread updates "counters" for "active" objects; either time elapsed doing something; or "counting down" until some state change, for example. Updating the UI is a different thread since it doesn't need to run as fast as the "counting" thread if the "speed" of the game is changed dramatically (in order to still see some "detail").

There's no obvious reason why a worker shouldn't be expected to miss some "seconds"; e.g. if the worker is busy working for more than one "second", then of course the next time it looks at the clock value, it will see a current-time that shows more than one second has passed.

That said, I can't see any reason to use a thread to simulate a clock; why not just have a get_current_virtual_time() function that the threads call, and implement that function to return a value derived from the value returned by time.time() ?

I'm trying to simulate a sort of warehouse, where the worker threads are meant to represent literal workers. They can't miss a few "seconds" of time because I need to track what these virtual workers are doing at every second, and i can't use virtual time or time.time() because I don't want to have to run the simulation in real time.
